# How to write a proper git pull with libgit2

Tags: c++, c, libgit2

I want to write a *C++* *libgit2* wrapper to perform some basic git operations because *libgit2* is too much atomic to be used as is (in my opinion).
As *libgit2* is written in *C*, it does not matter if I get a *C* or *C++* oriented solution, I will adapt it by myself.

I encounter difficulties with the `gitPull()` function that is supposed to be the *"git pull"* equivalent.

I planned to implement it as follows:

- [`git_remote_fetch()`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/remote/git_remote_fetch)
- [`git_annotated_commit_from_fetchhead()`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/annotated/git_annotated_commit_from_fetchhead)
- [`git_merge()`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/merge/git_merge) (with the previously got `git_annotated_commit`)
- [`git_commit_create()`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/commit/git_commit_create)

Considering that it is the proper way to do it (tell me if it is not), I struggle with two issues:

- **How to check if the fetched HEAD is equal or different to the local HEAD ?** (in order to know if the merge + commit are needed or not, in other words, if there is something to merge or if we already are up-to-date).
- **How or where to get the `git_oid * id` required by `git_annotated_commit_from_fetchhead()` ?** (the last parameter).

I know these questions may look quite basic but I could not find any exploitable information or example neither on the [*libgit2* API reference documentation](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD) nor in the [*libgit2* samples](https://libgit2.org/docs/guides/101-samples/).

I already have checked the already existing stackoverflow threads about this topic but none of them provide any exploitable code sample.

I will be very grateful if someone could give me some helpful information about how to achieve it or explain what I have misunderstood.

Comment: What do you mean by “atomic” (perhaps “low-level”)?

Comment: You can't achieve this without strong understanding how Git database (hash tree) works under hood.

Comment: @DavisHerring By atomic I mean that we need much more than one line to write the equivalent of a git command (I already have written a _"git clone url_", _"git add ."_, _"git commit -m message"_, _"git push"_ and _"git fetch"_). This being said, whether you understand or not what I mean by atomic is not the point of the question anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

> How to check if the fetched HEAD is equal or different to the local HEAD ?

You can call [`git_merge_analysis`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/merge/git_merge_analysis), which will tell you if you would need to do a merge.  In this case, `GIT_MERGE_ANALYSIS_UP_TO_DATE` indicates that there is no need to merge (`git merge` on the command line would respond with "Already up to date").

> How or where to get the git_oid * id required by git_annotated_commit_from_fetchhead()?

You can iterate the `FETCH_HEAD` file with [`git_repository_fetchhead_foreach`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/repository/git_repository_fetchhead_foreach).  It will provide you all the information necessary to generate an annotated commit from whichever remote branch you want to merge.

For example:

```
int fetchhead_cb(const char *ref_name, const char *remote_url, const git_oid *oid, unsigned int is_merge, void *payload)
{
    if (is_merge)
    {
        printf("reference: '%s' is the reference we should merge\n");
        git_oid_cpy((git_oid *)payload, oid);
    }
}

void pull(void)
{
    /* here's the id we want to merge */
    git_oid id_to_merge;

    /* Do the fetch */

    /* Populate id with the for_merge branch from FETCH_HEAD */
    git_repository_fetchhead_foreach(repo, fetchhead_cb, &id_to_merge);
}
```

(Note that you'd probably want to actually capture all the details of the `FETCH_HEAD` information - not just the id - so that you could create an annotated commit from the data, but this is an example of how the `git_repository_fetchhead_foreach` function works with callbacks.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally I found a way. I used `git_reference_name_to_id()` with _"HEAD"_ and _"FETCH_HEAD"_ to get the head_id and fetch_head_id and I compared them with `git_oid_equal()`. I also replaced `git_annotated_commit_from_fetchhead()` by `git_annotated_commit_lookup()` and I gave the fetch_head_id that I previously got.

Comment: In fact, I cannot use `git_repository_fetchhead_foreach` because I don't know what it is supposed to do nor how to fill the required callback (without any concrete example, I'm afraid I'll never understand this black magic). But as I only work on origin/master (only one remote and only one branch), my method (as I mentioned in the first comment) works well.

Comment: Seems reasonable, regardless, I added an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Actually I have no issue to provide a callback into a function parameter :) but I rather don't know how to fill the callback function body (`fetchhead_cb` in this case). With your example, I now know how to write it to get the IDs. I'm not sure if it is sufficient for a git pull.